How to get pointer of an overloaded template member function, getting the pointer of non templated one
I have the following scenario:
class C
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  std::shared_ptr<T> foo();

  std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> foo(std::string_view sw);
};

class DerivedFromC : public C
{
// no logic concerning foo
};

// in my bindings

pybind11::class_<DerivedFromC, ...some options...>(m, "Name")
  .def("foo", pybind11::overload_cast<std::string_view>(&DerivedFromC::foo));

This code doesn't compile with an error message:
[build] pythonbind.hpp(51,21): error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const detail::overload_cast_impl<basic_string_view<char, char_traits<char>>>'
[build]    51 |         .def("foo", pybind11::overload_cast<std::string_view>(&DerivedFromC::foo));
[build]       |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] ...\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\pybind11/detail/common.h(1106,20): note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Return'
[build]  1106 |     constexpr auto operator()(Return (*pf)(Args...)) const noexcept -> decltype(pf) {
[build]       |                    ^
[build] ...\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\pybind11/detail/common.h(1111,20): note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Return'
[build]  1111 |     constexpr auto operator()(Return (Class::*pmf)(Args...), std::false_type = {}) const noexcept
[build]       |                    ^
[build] ...\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\pybind11/detail/common.h(1117,20): note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
[build]  1117 |     constexpr auto operator()(Return (Class::*pmf)(Args...) const, std::true_type) const noexcept
[build]       |                    ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Do I do something incorrect or is there a special way for retrieving the pointer of that function? For me, it feels like the overload_cast function should have chosen the correct overload, as the templated one doesn't have any arguments.

The error isn't complaining about YOUR class.  It hasn't even reached that point yet.  It's complaining that there is no matching function for the overload_cast part.

@TimRoberts what do you mean by that? It's a function provided by the library that can be used to address a specific overload of the function. If I get it correct, you mean, that the function is not designed for the cases, where there are template and non-template overloads, right?

What version of C++ is this?  The docs talk about the alternatives:  https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html

I resolved my issue by manually static_cast-ing to the correct signature like the following.
pybind11::class_<DerivedFromC, ...some options...>(m, "Name")
  .def("foo", static_cast<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>(DerivedFromC::*)(std::string_view)>(&DerivedFromC::foo));

However, this doesn't seem elegant to me. So, if anyone has a better (more elegant) solution, will take that one as an answer.
